# Deploying multiple AWS Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

If I have several AWS Lambda functions, is it possible to specify deployment configuration for all three functions in a single YML file, or do I need to write specific YML file for each Lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes- you can have multiple functions in the same serverless framework service definition.

For example (you can see further information in the [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/)):

```yaml
service: myService

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10

functions:
  functionOne:
    handler: handler.functionOne
    description: optional description for your Lambda
    events: # All events associated with this function
      - http:
          path: users/create
          method: post
  functionTwo:
    handler: handler.functionTwo
    events:
      - s3: photos
  functionThree:
    handler: handler.functionThree
    memorySize: 512 # function specific
```